# Load Testing with TestNG

Tags: load, testng, soapui, performance-testing

I want to preface this with 'I am a complete noob' when it comes to Java. I have figured out how to consume a webservice and get some tests against that webservice using TestNG. I would now like to be able to take those TestNG tests and use them in a load test. Is there a way that I can either use these TestNG tests in SoapUI or is there another tool which I can use to perform load testing of the webservice?

I did find out about using @Test(invocationCount = , threadPoolSize = ) is that the extent of it, or can more be done within TestNG?

Comment: have you ever seen [this](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)?

Comment: With a combination of DataProviders and test Factory, you very well could load test.  Use a TestNG Factory to generate multiple copies of a existing parameterized test, each running in the thread group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the advice of Frank and looked that the link he provided.